# Login using Facebook SDK for Unity3d on android always sends old AccessToken

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm using the 5.1 SDK to log in on Android. This works first time round and I'm able to download profile pics and use the API with no issues.

When I restart the app, I'm prompted with the permissions screen again, even though I already given permissions.

When I look at the device log, I see 
{"key_hash":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXX=\n","user_id":"1234","expiration_timestamp":"1404234168","access_token":XXXXX...","opened":true}

(values replaced with XXXXX for privacy)

This expiration_timestamp is parsed to be "07/01/2014 17:02:48", which is wrong.

Every time I restart the app, I get the same permissions prompt.

Have I made an error with the setup or is this a known issue? Anybody know any workarounds?

Thanks all

Comment: The phone might be caching the old access token.  Try calling FB.Logout from within the game.

Comment: Thanx Brian, we tried that and its still happening.

Comment: All the Android devices this happens on does not have the FB app installed. When the app is installed, this does not happen.